# CSS or jQuery selector to match all descendants that are not descendants of other element

Tags: jquery, html, css

Is it possible to select all elements with `property=B` that are descendants of `typeof="A"`, but not descendants of any other `typeof` within `typeof="A"`?
But that should be a basic selector, not complex jQuery chain with `.find()` etc.

```
<div typeof="Y">
    <div property="B"></div>
    <div typeof="A">
        <sometags>
            <div property="B"></div> <--- this should match
        </sometags>
        <div typeof="X">
            <div property="B"></div>
        </div>
        <div property="B"></div> <--- this should match
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Something like this http://jsfiddle.net/akshay7/5wdsLtaf/ ?

Comment: Please add complete `HTML` code with proper tags

Comment: No, that would only match direct children, and I need descendants.

Comment: @Tushar I tried, better?

Comment: @Dmitri `div` should not self closing tags

Comment: Do you want css only or a jQuery selector will do

Comment: @ArunPJohny as said in the post, simple jQuery selectors will do.

Comment: Heh by the way, why do people -1 my question?))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are good with jQuery selectors try

```
jQuery('[typeof="A"] [property]:not([typeof="A"] [typeof] *)')
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ys34pza3/)

Comment: I think this may very well work! Will test and accept your answer.
Though it should obviously be `jQuery('[typeof="A"] [property]:not([typeof="A"] [typeof] *)')`

Comment: Can you correct the answer and fiddle to typeof=A and I will accept it?

Comment: Your advice has helped our open source project, thanks! https://review.typo3.org/#/c/39872/

Answer (score 1):

You need the `not` selector for this. I also think it's clearest if you split the "descendant" and "direct child" cases into seperate selector. Here's a working example:

```css
/* For demo purposes. */
div { border: 1px solid gray; padding: 5px; margin: 5px; }

div[typeof="A"] *:not([typeof]) div[property="B"],
div[typeof="A"] > div[property="B"] {
    color: red;
    background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div typeof="Y">
    <div property="B"></div>
    <div typeof="A">
        <sometags>
            <div property="B">this should match</div>
        </sometags>
        <div typeof="X">
            <div property="B">NO match</div>
        </div>
        <div property="B">this should match</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The downside is that this uses the `*` selector, which possibly leads to bad performance.

Another downside might be that it utilizes CSS3 selectors, I'm not sure of [exact browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3), specifically IE8.

Comment: That's a great answer as it works in CSS, but I'll accept the one by Arun P.Anthony as it's OK for me that it uses jQuery, and it should be more performant and better looking. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Try this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stanze/kxmxy6u2/), matching decendants of `type="A"` to select `property=B`

```
div[typeof="A"] > div[property="B"]{
    color: red;
}
```